# Coffescript For-Loop Not Working with Additional Variable Created

Tags: javascript, for-loop, coffeescript

So I am new to using coffescript and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I made it work using while loop but I just want to know how I can make it work using for loop. The loop only run once and returns an error of *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"*

```
squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square")
```

my cs code looks like this:

```
function = (col) ->
    for squares in squares
        squares.style.background = col
```

js output:

```
changeColor = function(col) {
  var j, len;
  for (j = 0, len = squares.length; j < len; j++) {
    squares = squares[j];
    squares.style.background = col;
  }
};
```

js output being accepted:

```
changeColor = function(col) {
  var j;
  for (j = 0; j < squares.length; j++) {
    squares[j].style.background = col;
  }
```

In my understanding, the converted js is correct but it won't accept the additional variables being declared. I might be wrong nonetheless. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Don't you mean `for square in squares`?

Comment: @muistooshort Hi. Sorry. But I don't think so. "squares" is the variable I used in cs/js and "square" is the class I used in html. I tried using square and rendered the following result.

Comment: `for (i = 0, len = squares.length; i < len; i++) {
  square = squares[i];
  squares[j].style.background = col;
}`

Comment: But you were saying, essentially `for x in x` and that doesn't make sense. You don't want your loop variable to have the same name as what you're iterating over. Hence my suggestion to use `for square in squares` rather than `for squares in squares`.

Answer (score 0):

In general if Coffeescript (and therefore Javascript) give you a an error message that has `undefined` in it than target of your call is not existing.

So in your case it says that `squares` is `undefined` and `undefined` indeed has no property named `background`. How do I know this? simply because the only line whery `style`is used is

```
squares.style.background = col
```

so `style`is called on `squares` and `squares` is undefined.

Now the next question is obviously **why** is `squares` undefined. My guess: there is no html element with the class `square` in your document. Just do

```
squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square")
console.log(squares)
```

to see what that call to `querySelectorAll` yields

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. There is a square class in my html however. I apologize as I used rather confusing naming for my files. Chrome Console: [div.square, div.square, div.square, div.square, div.square, div.square]